# Show that a subspace is locally connected

Tags: general-topology

Consider the real line with the topology generated by the open intervals of the form $(-\infty,a)$. Show that any subspace of this is locally connected.

My attempt: So we have the topology $T$ that containes open intervals  $(-\infty,a)$ (and of course the empty set and the real line itself).

Let $Y\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a subspace with topology $T$. $Y$ is locally connected if for every $y\in Y$, $y$ has a connected neighbouring basis.

How do I get from here?

Comment: Let $p\in Y$ and let's look at the system of neighborhoods $U_a=(-\infty,a)\cap Y$ for $a>p$. Note that any two open sets $U,V$ such that $(U\cup V)\cap Y=U_a$ will have to contain $p$ in at least one of them. Assume that $U$ contains $p$. If $V\cap Y$ is empty, then there is nothing to prove, because $U\cap Y$ and $V\cap Y$ are not disconnecting $U_a$. If $q\in V\cap Y$, then study two cases. Either $q\geq p$, in which case $p\in V\cap Y$, or $q<p$ in which case $q\in U\cap Y$. In both cases $(U\cap V)\cap Y$ is non-empty. Therefore, $U\cap Y$ and $V\cap Y$ don't disconnect $U_a$ either.

Comment: Aah okay, so $U_a$ is the neighborhoods of p?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the special property of $T$: if $U,V\in T$ then either $U\subseteq V$ or $V\subseteq U$. The topology is linearly ordered via inclusion. And this property is hereditary, any subspace has it.

And if a space has this property, then its every subset (including open neighbourhoods) is connected, simply because there are no disjoint open subsets. In particular it is locally connected.